# How to determine when HttpClient creates a new connection

Tags: java, connection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache's http library with JAVA to post multiple requests to the same server. I read in the documentation of HttpClient that it keeps connections alive and reuses them by default.

Is there any way to determine when the connection goes stale and a new one is set up ?

Comment: For what purpose? The whole idea is that you don't need to know. Most if not all HTTP clients do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do so is by turning on connection management context logging as described here

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html

This should provide you with detailed info about the internal state of the connection manager and the pool of persistent connections.